# How to return an image using turtle.bgpic()

Tags: python, image, gif, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will show me a picture of a map but when I run the code it's not returning the image or any sort of error. After doing a bit of research I don't think I need any other code but any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(720,360)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
screen.bgpic('map.gif')
```

Answer (score 2):

Is it flash back？Maybe you need suspend the program because end of execution or add
`screen.mainloop()`
as one solution

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

To make the window stay open, you need `screen.mainloop()`. What this does is to keep the window open and run any code that is necessary such as key presses. You simply place this at the end of the code and the final code looks like this...

#### Code

```
import turtle
screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(720,360)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
screen.bgpic('map.gif')
screen.mainloop()
```

**Note:** You need `screen.mainloop()` or `turtle.mainloop()` (if you haven't created a screen object) at the end of all turtle projects if you want them to run.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! It is now certainly trying to run something but it is taking a very long time. I've restarted the kernel, open Jupyter notebook in a new browser, and tried running the code on its own but it is still just thinking about it. Any tips?

Comment: Ok, I'm now just getting the error TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable. I think this means that there is something wrong with the environment where I'm trying to run the code. I am using Jupyter Notebook, which I thought would work. Does anyone have any info about this??

Comment: I don't really use Jupyter in the web, I mostly use it on VS Code. I'd recommend VS Code. Have you tried exporting as a .py file or copying and pasting the code into a .py file and running it through IDLE or anything not on the web? @LEJ2474 I have tested it on IDLE and it works. You can use any offline editor to run it and it should work. I don't see why it doesn't work on Jupyter though. Try making a new environment?

Comment: @Programmer I just felt that it needed more explanation. The first one wasn't clear and needed more detail.

Comment: That's good but  wtriting "the final code looks like this" and not _adding_ `screen.mainloop()` to it is not right ;)

Comment: @LEJ2474 try importing the os module and do `os.environ["DISPLAY"] = "name-of-the-display"` at the top of your code !

Comment: @Programmer Sorry. I thought I did. Thank you.